# Vector support in Snowflake warehouse

Tags: amazon-web-services, vector, etl, data-warehouse, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a vector data in my input field and I want to store this data in snowflake. So, can we store vector data in snowflake?

Comment: Your question isn't really clear here @ctom - what do you mean by a vector ? do you mean an indexed sequence of values like a vector in Scala?

Comment: yes, can we store indexed value (vector value) in snowflake warehouse?. just like bigquery supports storage of vector data

Answer (score 1):

You should be able store it as one of the semi-structured data types as in [the documentation](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/data-types-semistructured.html#data-types):

```sql
create table demonstration1 (
    id integer,
    array1 array,
    variant1 variant,
    object1 object
    );

insert into demonstration1 (id, array1, variant1, object1) 
  select 
    1, 
    array_construct(1, 2, 3), 
    parse_json(' { "key1": "value1", "key2": "value2" } '),
    parse_json(' { "outer_key1": { "inner_key1A": "1a", "inner_key1B": "1b" }, '
              ||
               '   "outer_key2": { "inner_key2": 2 } } ')
    ;

insert into demonstration1 (id, array1, variant1, object1) 
  select 
    1, 
    array_construct(1, 2, 3, null), 
    parse_json(' { "key1": "value1", "key2": NULL } '),
    parse_json(' { "outer_key1": { "inner_key1A": "1a", "inner_key1B": NULL }, '
              ||
               '   "outer_key2": { "inner_key2": 2 } '
              ||
               ' } ')
  ;
```